# RL high pass filter behaving strangely

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fASwXT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I built a RL filter using a 56 ohm resistor and a 10 mH inductor. I sent a 308Hz 3% duty cycle signal (that was generated using an op-amp circuit) through the filter. The output that I got was quite strange. When I turned the signal generator on, its output changed from a clear square wave to mess with a negative and a positive spike.

[image: Output of signal generator]

[image]

Does anyone know why this is happening? I though maybe the inductive load was somehow overloading the signal generator but I unfortunately don't have any other inductors on hand to test this.

Comment: Most signal generators have 50 ohm output impedance. You need to consider that in your analysis.

Comment: It would help if you would add a schematic showing, clearly, how the RL is driven, what specs does the signal generator have, where and how the voltage is probed.

Comment: Click the [Edit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/589244/edit) link below your question to access a built-in schematic editor.

Comment: Looks like it's ringing.  Try removing the L and see if you get the same results.  If so, your opamp circuit is the culprit.

Comment: I'm wondering about the actual value of your inductor L1. I simulated  the output of your circuit (OA2, R8, L1) but could not reproduce the yellow and blue traces in your lower image. However, when I lowered the inductor value from 10 milliHenry (10mH)  to 10 **micro**Henry (10uH) the sharp spikes appeared coincident with the leading and trailing edges of the drive pulse.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting too much strain on that op amp, I suspect.  With 56 ohms real and roughly 20j from the inductor, unless you picked a special high drive, you're going to be hard pressed to drive that real hard.  You might be able to boost it a bit using power FETs as long as it only needs to be a square wave.

Comment: I believe you are correct. I replaced the resistor with different ones increasing the resistance as I go and saw that the wave form will gradually gain it shape back as the resistance increased. I also did the same with the inductor but got the opposite result as I decreased the inductor size the wave form got its shape back.